# Alert continua aparecendo não importa o que eu faça!

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Peguei o código de um carrinho de compras na internet. E tem a página do carrinho onde o cliente pode aumentar ou diminuir a quantidade do produto. O problema desse código é que cada vez que vc aumenta ou diminui uma quantidade ele aparece um alert "Quantidade atualizada", eu já tentei de tudo já exclui a parte do código que tem esse alert, já modifiquei no php e até agora o alert continua a ser exibido. Queria que ele parasse de ser exibido cada vez que você atualiza a quantidade. Vou deixar o código resumido, só as partes que importam.

cart.js

```html
 add : function (id) {
  // add () : add item to cart
  // PARAM id : product ID

cart.ajax({
  url : "4b-ajax-cart.php",
  data : {
    req : "add",
    product_id : id
  },
  load : function (res) {
    cart.count();
    // @TODO
    alert(res);
  }
});
  },
```

carrinho.php

```html
<!--- Botão para aumentar e diminuir quantidade ---->

 <td><input class="form-control" id='qty_<?= $id ?>' onchange='cart.change(<?= $id ?>);' type='number' value='<?= $qty ?>'/></td>

<!--- Fim botão para aumentar e diminuir quantidade ---->

 /* [Aumentar e diminuir qty] */
  case "change":
if ($_POST['qty'] == 0) {
  unset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['product_id']]);
} else {
  $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['product_id']] = $_POST['qty'];
    die ("Quantidade atualizada");
}
   die ("Produto removido");
break;
```

Comment: Se você retirou esse `alert`,  limpou o cache e recarregou a página mas não funcionou, use a IDE para pesquisar todos _"alert"_ dentro da pasta do projeto, talvez tenha algum outro além desse e não percebeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova o  `alert(res);` do load da requisição ajax, não entendo o porque de utilizar o `die`, retorne uma string, trate seu retorno com a função `success` do ajax.

Comment: removi o alert(res) mas o alert continua. Tenho que desabilitar o Network do navegador, limpar cache e cookies?

Comment: Quando removo o die, o alert continua mas sem nenhuma mensagem, só a caixa de dialogo mesmo.

Comment: Algum lugar esta inserindo o alert(), ele não é exibido se não existe no código. Sugiro a utilizar um padrão MVC, se é um link externo, pode utilizar o legado jquery so para tratar o retorno.

Comment: Interessante, na pasta do projeto eu já exclui o alert(res). E quando abro a IDE do navegador, o alert(res) continua aparecendo. E se eu excluo ele na IDE o alert some. A pergunta é por que ele continua aparecendo na IDE se já o apaguei na pasta original?